# Blender 2.8, API, select_set( action = "SELECT") TypeError

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

According to [Blender 2.8 WIKI API changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Dev:2.8/Source/LayersCollections/API-Changes),
 the following script is now obsolete:

```
bpy.context.object.select = True
```

replaced with:

```
bpy.context.object.select_set( action = "SELECT")
```

However that's throwing a TypeError: required paramater "state" not specified..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
bpy.context.object.select_set( state = True, view_layer = None)
```

That's the right syntax in Blender 2.8 Beta to the date, apparently the WIKI is not updated